# space between 3 columns with border in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want some space between my columns but I am not getting it after adding border to them. How can I do it?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" style= "border:1px solid black">
          <p>Stuff that fills this column</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4" style= "border:1px solid black">
          <p>Stuff that fills this column</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4" style= "border:1px solid black">
          <p>Stuff that fills this column</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using `col-*-4`, you should use `col-*-3` as it won't span the entire width. Plus I added the following CSS:

```
.col-xs-3:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 12%;
}
```

Heres the working fiddle for that:https://jsfiddle.net/6jyye76e/5/

Comment: margin for columns is not the best practice, that could change and turn your site upside down. NOT recommended.

Comment: Its good that you pointed out something but it would have been better if you provided an alternate better solution to the scenario as well.@clusterBuddy

Answer (score 0):

You need `margin-left`:

```
.col-md-4:not(:first) {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

EDIT:

To `display` the items as columns, you need this additional rule:

```
.row .col-md-4 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6jyye76e/2/) fiddle.

Comment: doesn't seem to make any differnece.

Comment: @AakashThakur can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Have a look at it yourself. They aren't even showing as columns. https://jsfiddle.net/6jyye76e/1/

Comment: @AakashThakur you need to display the items as inline-block, see my edit.

Comment: @AakashThakur it is the "this" word in the last sentence of the answer. Please right-click on it and open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need use selector do css class change first div tag.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.col-md-4:not(:first-child) {
   margin-left: 5px;
   background-color: red;
}
.col-md-4 {
   margin-left: 0px;
   border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
   width:calc(33.3333333% - 5px) !important;
}

</style
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>Stuff that fills this column</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>Stuff that fills this column</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>Stuff that fills this column</p>
     </div>
</div>
```